# Where is a good area to farm arrows and/or bolts?

Tags: dark-souls

I have a bow and a crossbow but no arrows at all, so anyone know a good area to farm them?

Comment: It's pretty difficult to farm arrows or bolts.  You're better off farming souls and then buying them from a blacksmith.  There's one in Undead Parish, which is pretty near the beginning of the game.

Comment: Could just buy them from the undead merchant in the Burg. It's closer than the blacksmith.

Comment: Over read about him but don't know where he is located, also heated of a female one

Comment: The Undead Merchant is located to the right of the corridor where you first see the red drake there are two spearman on a platform and to the for left of this plat form is a staircase covered with boxes role into them and you'll find the staircase. down there and straight through the door facing there he is :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Originally it was fairly difficult to obtain arrows easily, as the [Male Undead Merchant](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/undead-merchant-male) in the Undead Burg and the [Giant Blacksmith](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/giant-blacksmith) in Anor Londo were originally the only two merchants to sell any kind of arrows, but now almost every merchant and certainly every blacksmith sells arrows and bolts, so as GnomeSlice suggested, farm souls and then buy the arrows from a merchant.